# Understanding lemma found in proof of quotient construction for DFAs

Tags: finite-automata

> Lemma 13.6    $p \in F \Longleftrightarrow [p] \in F'$
>
> *Proof.* The direction $\Rightarrow$ is immediate from the definition of $F'$. For the direction $\Leftarrow$, we need to show that if $p \approx q$ and $p \in F$, then $q \in F$. In other words, every $\approx$-equivalence class is either a subset of $F$ or disjoint from $F$. This follows immediately by taking $x = \epsilon$ in the definition of $p \approx q$. $\quad\square$

The excerpt above found in Dexter C. Kozen's Automata and Computability.  This lemma is found in a proof of the Quotient Construction for DFA.

I do not understand how the author concludes that if one wants to show $[p] \in F' \implies p \in F$ (1), then it is equivalent to showing that $p≈q$ and $p \in F \implies q \in F$ (2). Can someone please provide as detailed as possible an explanation of why if we want to show (1) it is equivalent to show (2)? Any idea on why the author does not feel the need to justify this?

Comment: Can you provide definitions for the different objects here to make your question self contained? My guess is that $[p]$ is the equivalence class of $p$ for some equivalence relation and that $F'=\{[p]\mid p\in F\}$. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I appreciate this feedback. Is there not a standard notation for this type of mathematics or something? Can I not assume that someone who is knowledgeable enough to answer my question also is familiar with this exact notation and defintions?

Comment: Like I am providing enough background information I think. I tell you the author, the name of the concept "quotient construction..." It is impossible to make this post self contained. It would require me to provide  an entire 100 pages of a textbook. To me, it seems tantamount to asking someone to provide the definition of an integral/derivative in a post about calculus. Correct me if I'm wrong, and please do elaborate. Regardless, I do appreciate the feedback. On a last note, I will be very appreciative of anyone who can answer my question, as not understanding this is frustrating me a lot

Comment: Your question is impossible to understand, since you are not explaining the following symbols: $F,F',\approx,[p]$.

Comment: Do not revert edits to improve your question.  This site is a community resource, which means that others are allowed and encouraged to edit your question to improve it.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/editing.

Comment: Do not use images to represent text or mathematics.  This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics. You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).  We require that you give proper attribution to the sources of all copied material.

Comment: It doesn't take 100 pages to define the notation that is used in the question.  This site is composed of volunteers: if you would like an answer, it is in your interests to make sure the question is understandable and self-contained.

Comment: @D.W. please stop editing my post. In my view, the edits you want to make reduce the quality of my post.

Comment: @JMF9, I'm sorry, but as previously explained, that is not a request that can be accommodated on this site.  If you would like to explain in what way quality has been reduced I imagine people might be willing to hear.  As previously explained, we do not want to see images of text, and I do not see how replacing images with a transcription lowers quality; in my opinion it increases the quality of the question.  Please do not continue reverting edits to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Let us start with explaining the notation:

- $F$ is the set of accepting states of some DFA.
- We define an equivalence relation $\approx$ on the states of the DFA as follows: $p \approx q$ if for all words $x$, $\hat\delta(p,x) \in F$ iff $\hat\delta(q,x)$, where $\hat\delta$ is the transition function of the DFA (extended from symbols to words).
- We denote the equivalence class of a state $p$ by $[p]$.
- $F' = \{ [p] : p \in F \}$.

Now suppose that $[p] \in F'$. According to the definition of $F'$, $[p] = [q]$ for some $q \in F$. Standard properties of equivalence relations imply that $[p] = [q]$ iff $p \approx q$. By definition of $\approx$, $\hat\delta(p,x) \in F$ iff $\hat\delta(q,x) \in F$ for all words $x$. Taking $x = \epsilon$, we see that $p = \hat\delta(p,\epsilon) \in F$ iff $q = \hat\delta(q,\epsilon) \in F$. Since $q \in F$, this shows that indeed $p \in F$.

Comment: It seems like you understood the notation just fine. This answer in no way addresses my question. I understand what the lemma says and what the lemma means. I do not understand how the author determines that showing statement (1) is the same as showing statement (2). Also, the edits you made to my post were unproductive. Again, this response in no way addresses the question.

Comment: I didn't "understand the notation just fine". I looked it up in the textbook. There is no reason for me to have to do that. You should provide all necessary information in the post. Granted, you can't tell which information is necessary as a student, but when people tell you to explain your notation, doing it would increase the probability that you will get help.

Comment: I'm sorry that you don't like my answer. Perhaps someone else will step in with a better one.

Comment: If you want to get help on this site, you have to abide by site rules.

Comment: The site is curated by users. The goal is to create a repository of high quality questions and answers. As part of that, it is better that text in questions be searchable, which means that actual text is preferred over images. That was the main goal of my original edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121061/discussion-between-jmf9-and-yuval-filmus).